# Difference between handle_info and handle_in of Channel

Tags: phoenix-framework

I went through https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html. It seems like handle_info has similar functions as handle_in. Under what circumstances should I use handle_info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage for `handle_info` is the same as the usage in [GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_info/2) and is commonly seen in behaviours ([GenEvent](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/GenEvent.html#c:handle_info/2), [DBConnection](https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/DBConnection.html#c:handle_info/2))

> Invoked to handle all other messages.
>
> msg is the message and state is the current state of the GenServer. When  a timeout occurs the message is :timeout.
>
> Return values are the same as handle_cast/2..

If you send a message to the process manually (using `send`) then it will be handled using `handle_info`. `handle_info` is also used to notify of a process going down if the process (the channel in this case) is monitoring it.